# Word 2010: Repeat table row as header with image

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I'm trying to create a repeating table header in Word 2010, and I want to include an image inside one of the cells in this header. I've got the table cells themselves repeating correctly, but the image inside the cell is only on the first page. How do I get the image to repeat as well?

Comment: I can't help you, except to say that it "should" be easy. [I did it](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LpkpM.png) in a copy of Word 2013 that I installed just a few days ago, and I haven't messed with the settings at all, so what you want seems to be default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing making the image a watermark and embedding in the background of the document. I'm sure it's not the most elegant solution, but it worked.